# Migrated Exchange 2007 to VMware, cannot start Exchange services - DNS / IP issue?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, vmware-esxi, exchange, exchange-2007

I had a test Exchange 2007 system in Microsoft VPC which I had converted to VMware ESXi format.  However when I powered on the machine it was automatically using the default VLAN which is connected to the live network.  Because running under VMware effectively changed the "hardware" of the machine, this resulted in a change of the network adapter so I lost the static IPs and it picked up a new IP from the live network.  I can only imagine that this screwed up DNS, AD and Exchange.

So I created a new VLAN which holds a 'local only' network, configured IP as before but now Exchange cannot start.  I keep getting 1053 errors (service cannot start in a timely fashion).  I see nothing relevant in the event viewer.  I have a gut feeling it is a DNS problem, but the settings looks fine to me.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Which Exchange service is it that cannot start?

Comment: Does the Exchange server have connecticvity to the same network that the DC is on, or is Exchange installed on the DC?

Comment: I can start AD Topology, Information Store, Service Host and System Attendant.  All the other Automatic services won't start, including Transport. Error 1053.

Exchange is not on the DC and both machines can see each other.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange must be able to see the Active Directory to which it's organization is installed.

If you have a different domain in this localized environment, you'll have to prepare this domain:

setup /PrepareAD [/OrganizationName:  ]